# Discrepancy in Typescript Library <> Angular WebApp object instantiation: properties missing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two angular Projects. The first one is a library and the second one is a regular Angular webapp. In my first project (i.e. the library) I have for example the following code

```
class User {
    firstName: string; 
    lastName: string;
}

function instantiate<T extends Object>(constructor: new () => T) : T {
    const obj = new constructor();
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    console.log('Object is:', obj);
    console.log('Keys are:', keys);
    return obj;
}

function testForStackOverflow() {
    instantiate(User);
}
```

**Output**

> Object is: User {firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined}

> Keys are: (2) ['firstName', 'lastName']

So the above method creates a new `User` with all empty fields. This is desired behaviour.

But when I copy-paste this code in my webapp, it yields the following output

> Object is: User {}

> Keys are: (0) []

It seems that for the library, something different somehow creates the class with empty fields whereas for the webap I have an empty object without any fields. AFAIK I did not change any configuration to be like this.

Both projects were compiled with the latest version of every package so it is certainly not a versioning issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is explained by `useDefineForClassFields` is `tsconfig`.

With `true` you'll get the class fields.

But currently the Angular CLI sets automatically the value to `false` (this change was made for v15).

Comment: Thanks. There was indeed a difference in the compiler target which, when set to a more recent version, solved the issue.